# PHP C# Named Pipes

Tags: c#, php, ipc, named-pipes

I recently asked a question on IPC between C# and PHP and followed an answer up suggesting named pipes. For this, I searched the Internet for an appropriate example of named pipes using solely C# as `client` and `server` simultaneously and modified it so it'd run asynchronously:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Start();
    new AutoResetEvent(false).WaitOne();
}

private static async void Start()
{
    StartServer();
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    StartClient();
}

private static async void StartClient()
{
    var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("TestPipe");
    await client.ConnectAsync();

    var reader = new StreamReader(client);
    var writer = new StreamWriter(client);
    while (true)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) break;
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(input);
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
    }
}

private static async void StartServer()
{
    await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("TestPipe");
        await server.WaitForConnectionAsync(); 
        var reader = new StreamReader(server);
        var writer = new StreamWriter(server);
        while(true) // should be !reader.EndOfStream(), doesn't work tho
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("RECEIVED > " + line);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    });
}
```

So if I now type `Hello` into the console, it is going to return `RECEIVED > Hello`, which is fine and looks like it's brilliantly working. I entirely understand this in C#. However, this changes when PHP comes into play: I found less good examples (or even tutorials) for named pipes in PHP and the usage. Now what I found [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.posix-mkfifo.php#77137) brought me one step further, but only one.

In PHP, I seem to lack the understanding of the whole complex. My target is to 'feed' my C# server with tasks in the form of commands (e.g. `create document id=12`). The server (which is also running largely asynchronous) then shall give something back stating whether it has worked out or not (also using the `id`). So for example, my server's reply could be:

```
document id=12 created successfully
```

or

```
document id=12 error
```

Of course, I'll need my both applications to parse this and process these replies further, however, this is not the nub of the matter at this point. I need my PHP application to schedule tasks to C# and get the 'ping-back' ('error or not', you could say). I don't even need multiple ping backs, so for example a status update of the C# application frequently sending this, I only need one final statement whether it has worked or not.

Taking a look at the example I found on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.posix-mkfifo.php#77137), this does not tell me too much about it:

```
<?php
   $pipe="/tmp/pipe";
   $mode=0600;
   if(!file_exists($pipe)) {
      // create the pipe
      umask(0);
      posix_mkfifo($pipe,$mode);
   }
   $f = fopen($pipe,"w");
   fwrite($f,"hello");  //block until there is a reader
   unlink($pipe); //delete pipe

?>
```

And this is the non-blocking reader:

```
<?php
   $pipe="/tmp/pipe";
   if(!file_exists($pipe)) {
      echo "I am not blocked!";
   }
   else {
      //block and read from the pipe
      $f = fopen($pipe,"r");
      echo fread($f,10);
   }
?>
```

The first, blocking variant, does not qualify for Windows since `posix` is not available on Windows and my C# application requires this. The example shows a blocked pipe (what exactly is this even? I could think of an existent pipe considered blocked, since `if(!file_exists($pipe))` suggests this). However, this would mean that I could only handle one task at the same time with my C# server, which is not the requirement.

This is the procedure it is supposed to be:

1. User presses 'download'
2. PHP Action is fired (inside my `Laravel Controller`)
3. PHP schedules a task to the C# server via pipe
4. C# server receives it and processes it
5. C# server finishes it and tells PHP that it is finished (or error thrown, respectively) via pipe
6. The PHP (Laravel Controller) already awaits this answer and renders it to the user

Where I'm stuck is the point where pipes can be blocked, since this (according to the reference on the PHP docs page comments section) would mean if a certain pipe is blocked and I want multiple tasks to be ran at the same time, I need to create a new one, which my C# server must be aware of, too, which in conclusion means I can only set a very limited number of pipes, so to speak 'possible' slots for 'work' or 'tasks' of the server which a user of the web application can join into [the slot] and afterwards the slot's cleared. Howsoever, this'd destroy the concept of my C# asynchronous server and the principal idea behind it, and I can't think of this as the only solution.

I'm looking forward to seeing some suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: Or you can use [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/)